# Генерация псевдо-Id в MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Для начала оговорю рабочую среду: .net core + Entity Framework Core + MySQL.

Теперь к делу: в моей БД есть примерно следующая таблица:

```
(PK) Id:string      // обыкновенный GUID
     LocalId:int    // Id, который будет видеть пользователь
                    // Основная проблема в том, что LocalId не уникален
(FK) UserId:int     // Уникальна комбинация UserId-LocalId
     OtherData:any
```

Простая авто-генерация не подходит вот почему: для каждого пользователя нужно поддерживать сплошную нумерацию. То есть не должно быть такого, что у первого пользователя `LocalId` идут 1-5, затем `LocalId` 6-10 второго пользователя, затем 11-n первого и так далее.

Два единственных варианта, которые я пока нашёл - это всё же костыли:

1. Завести у пользователя поле `LastLocalId:int`, и при добавлении данных (а они добавляются пачками по 100+ штук за раз) взять это значение, ручками наращивать `LocalId` для каждой новой строки данных, а в конце последний получившийся `LocalId` записать в `LastLocalId`. Минус этого подхода я вижу в том, что если пользователь запустит 2 потока на добавление данных (к примеру, с разных устройств зайдёт), то один из потоков словит исключение (если не оба)
2. Перед добавлением данных глянуть на самый крупный `LocalId` для пользователя, а дальше этот вариант ровно ничем не отличается от первого - ручное наращивание `LocalId` (пожалуй, единственное отличие, которое будет достигнуто - при удалении последней записи нумерация собьётся и последний `LocalId` повторится)

Проблему обоих вышеперечисленных способов (возможность словить исключение при попытке параллельно добавить данные) можно решить путём издевательства над БД - перед добавлением каждой строки в таблицу заново запрашивать `LocalId` (вместо того, чтобы пачкой добавить все данные)

Я полагаю, что я всё-таки не один такой человек, кому понадобился псевдо-Id. И надеюсь, что в MySQL придумали настройки, которые позволят реализовать нужный мне функционал более оптимизированно и потоко-безопасно

**UPD:** точная используемая версия БД - 10.3.17-MariaDB

Результат команды `SHOW CREATE TABLE marketplacepurchases;`:

```
 CREATE TABLE `MarketplacePurchases` (
  `Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `LocalId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `OrderNumber` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `Currency` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAccount` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerFullName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerFirstName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerLastName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAddressStreet` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAddressZipCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAddressCity` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAddressCountry` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerAddressCountryCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SellerEmail` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAccount` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerFullName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerFirstName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerLastName` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAddressStreet` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAddressZipCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAddressCity` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAddressCountry` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerAddressCountryCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuyerEmail` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaidDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RequestedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoodsRecieveDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArchivedDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Note` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippingMethod` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippingCost` float NOT NULL,
  `PaymentMethod` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalAmountWithoutShipping` float NOT NULL,
  `TotalAmountWithShipping` float NOT NULL,
  `ListingFormat` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `LastModifedDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `MarketplaceLastModifedDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `OrderStatus` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaymentStatus` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserMarketplaceDataId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_MarketplacePurchases_UserMarketplaceDataId_LastModifedDate` (`UserMarketplaceDataId`,`LastModifedDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MarketplacePurchases_UserMarketplaceDatas_UserMarketplaceDat~` FOREIGN KEY (`UserMarketplaceDataId`) REFERENCES `UserMarketplaceDatas` (`Id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: А зачем перед добавлением записи вообще понадобилось получать последний localId ? Как вы добавляете записи ? `insert into table(userId, localId) select 1, coalesce(max(localId), 0)+1 from table where userId=1 for update` Вставит запись со следующим localId атомарно получив его и заблокирует запись с последним (перед добавлением) localId до конца транзакции. Так что другие потоки будет ждать пока вставка не будет окончена. при желании запрос можно доработать что бы он вставил сразу много строк. возможно for update перестраховка.

Comment: 1) Укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию MySQL. 2) Покажите ПОЛНОСТЬЮ структуру таблицы, выполнив `SHOW CREATE TABLE имя_таблицы` через консольный клиент `mysql.exe` (или иным аналогичным способом, но минуя всякие "умные" клиенты, от которых получаешь "сочинение по мотивам"), и пример данных (2-3 записи).

Comment: @Akina , дополнил вопрос

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то Вы хотите, чтобы в поле `LocalId` шла непрерывная нумерация от 1 и до общего количества, причём индивидуально для каждого `UserId`, верно? Тогда: 1) существует ли некое поле (скажем, какое-то из полей с датой), сортировка по которому полностью соответствует требуемой нумерации (т.е. если для одного юзера у одной записи дата меньше, чем у другой, то и этот сгенерённый номер также будет гарантированно меньше)? 2) Удаляются ли записи из этой таблицы, или всё, что туда попало, остаётся там навечно?

Comment: *Уникальна комбинация UserId-LocalId* - я не вижу в структуре ничего, что обеспечивает эту уникальность. Так что это утверждение - не истина, а всего лишь надежда, и то верная лишь до первого сбоя... Кстати, а что есть вообще `IserId` в показанной структуре?

Comment: @Akina , Уникальна комбинация UserId-LocalId - мой косяк, забыл последнюю миграцию применить. Задумку Вы мою верно поняли - непрерывная нумерация, индивидуальная для каждого пользователя. 1) Нет, такого поля нет 2) Да, данные могут быть удалены

Comment: Ну для MariaDB я для конкурентной среды не вижу вменяемого решения кроме как использовать транзакцию, которая полностью блокирует таблицу (или по мягкому варианту, как описано в комментарии @Mike). В MySQL можно было бы переместить таблицу на MyISAM, где есть соответствующий механизм "второго автоинкремента" (как это аукнется на всём остальном - другой вопрос, так что впереди замаячил бы вертикальный шардинг).